# JavaScript - bind under multiple layers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In JavaScript, I want to reference the external object.

More specifically, I have the following React code. Within the nesting I want to reference `this.props`.

```
var Table = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    buttons: [{
      text: '',
      actions: function(e) {
      //HERE I want to reference this.props
      }   
     },
    //some other elements
    ]
  //some other code
  }

});
```

How can I reference `this.props` of `Table` from within the `actions` function?